# Retrieve data from ortuman/SwiftForms after submit button click

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using this pods from cocopods ortuman/SwiftForms on submit button it is providing data in this format

```
{
    company = test;
    email = test;
    interst = M;
    location = test;
    name = test;
    phone = 8765;
    picker = E;
    position = test;
    textview = test;
    website = test;
}
```

I am having trouble extracting any data from this like company is key then test is value i.e what I want if I don't enter any thing it returns the data as

```
{
    company = "<null>";
    email = "<null>";
    interst = M;
    location = "<null>";
    name = "<null>";
    phone = "<null>";
    picker = E;
    position = "<null>";
    textview = "<null>";
    website = "<null>";
}
```

Comment: So, What is the issue?

Comment: It is providing the data in string format i need the data extracted on basees of let say company or email.

Comment: can you specify, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get the value of company as test and value of phone as 8765.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key, value) in self.form.formValues() {
    println("\(key) = \(value)")
}
```

or

```
if let company = self.form.formValues()["company"] as? String {
            println(company)
}
```